# YouTube API Error "Failed (unable to convert video file)" but Video gets converted with manual Upload

Tags: php, api, zend-framework, youtube

After I upload a video with PHP YouTube API this error "Failed (unable to convert video file)" shows up in the Video Manager.

And I am using the example from the PHP API documentation. And other people use the same code and it works for them, what is wrong with this code?

```
        <?php

    require_once 'Zend/Loader.php'; // the Zend dir must be in your include_path
    Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_YouTube');
    Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_AuthSub');


        Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_YouTube');
        Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin');

    $authenticationURL = 'https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin';
    //filtrunet
        $httpClient = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient(
                      $username     = 'username',
                      $password         = 'password',
                      $service      = 'youtube',
                      $client       = null,
                      $source       = 'source',
                      $loginToken       = null,
                      $loginCaptcha     = null,
                      $authenticationURL);

        $devkey = 'devkey';

        $yt = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube($httpClient, '', '', $devkey);




    // Note that this example creates an unversioned service object.
    // You do not need to specify a version number to upload content
    // since the upload behavior is the same for all API versions.
    $yt = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube($httpClient);

    // create a new VideoEntry object
    $myVideoEntry = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube_VideoEntry();
    $myVideoEntry->setVideoPrivate();
    // create a new Zend_Gdata_App_MediaFileSource object
    $filesource = $yt->newMediaFileSource('video.mov');
    $filesource->setContentType('video/quicktime');
    // set slug header
    $filesource->setSlug('video.mov');

    // add the filesource to the video entry
    $myVideoEntry->setMediaSource($filesource);

    $myVideoEntry->setVideoTitle('My Test video');
    $myVideoEntry->setVideoDescription('My Test video');
    // The category must be a valid YouTube category!
    $myVideoEntry->setVideoCategory('Autos');

    // Set keywords. Please note that this must be a comma-separated string
    // and that individual keywords cannot contain whitespace
    $myVideoEntry->SetVideoTags('cars, funny');

    // set some developer tags -- this is optional
    // (see Searching by Developer Tags for more details)
    $myVideoEntry->setVideoDeveloperTags(array('mydevtag', 'anotherdevtag'));

    // set the video's location -- this is also optional
    $yt->registerPackage('Zend_Gdata_Geo');
    $yt->registerPackage('Zend_Gdata_Geo_Extension');
    $where = $yt->newGeoRssWhere();
    $position = $yt->newGmlPos('37.0 -122.0');
    $where->point = $yt->newGmlPoint($position);
    $myVideoEntry->setWhere($where);

    // upload URI for the currently authenticated user
    $uploadUrl = 'http://uploads.gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/uploads';

    // try to upload the video, catching a Zend_Gdata_App_HttpException, 
    // if available, or just a regular Zend_Gdata_App_Exception otherwise
    try {
                $newEntry = $yt->insertEntry($myVideoEntry, $uploadUrl,
        'Zend_Gdata_YouTube_VideoEntry');
                $id = $newEntry->getVideoId(); // YOUR ANSWER IS HERE :)
                echo $id; 
        }

    catch (Zend_Gdata_App_HttpException $httpException) {
      echo $httpException->getRawResponseBody();
    } catch (Zend_Gdata_App_Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

    ?>
```

Thanks

Comment: Same here. That's terrible. Spending several weeks building a huge app, taking for grant Youtube will digest your file because the manual uploader works, then realizing the API cannot digest it. Not enough space here to say how it's disguting.

Comment: did you find a way to solve the issue? I am having the same problem it works on local machine but not on server

Comment: @LéonPelletier did you find a way to solve it?

Comment: For now I - think - it's possible to force the detection by being more specific in the Content-Type / X-Upload-Content-Type MIME. I think, for example, that where all my attempts with a mjpeg file encapsulated in a .avi that has a video/avi failed, they succeed by writing "video/mjpeg", but I'm not 100% sure. Fresh news from some minutes ago.

Comment: There's a lot of artificial intelligence and algorithms behind these processes, so there's probably a complicated workaround to design to have the API digesting it as easily as the Youtube website. The main problem is probably that on the website, the file is pre-analysed in javascript, but using the API, the file is totally unknown.